Android studio crear alarma
Estoy intentando implementar una alarma y un action Dial. Es extraño que no me de ningún error, pero al pulsar el botón de Crear alarma o llamada al botón 112 no la activa. Alguien puede echarme una mano?
Os copio los archivo de manifest, activity xml y activity.java. Lo trato de activar con onclick o  a través de un id pero  consigo activar la alarma ni el botón de llamada
package com.enrique.alarma;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });


    }


    public void estableceAlarma(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent (AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)

                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Ir a trabajar")
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,23)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 20);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            startActivity(intent);


    }
}

public void marcarTelefono112(View view) {

    Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:112"));
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){


        startActivity(intent);
    }



}

}

El intent para programar una alarma necesita de un permiso en el manifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

Para abrir el dial, en cambio, no se necesita permiso, debería funcionar sin él.
Yo tengo programado el código en dos botones de esta manera, y me funciona, poniendo el permiso solo para la alarma:
    Button boton1 = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarma);
    boton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Ir al trabajo")
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 11)
                    .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No existe una app para esto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    Button boton2 = findViewById(R.id.btnMarcar);
    boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:112"));

            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

